# About monitor in sqlserver

Tags: mfc

In MFC application,i wish it can give me a tag when i update a table.If any system command can do this in SQLServer?
i need to  reload pictures with the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server can notify you when a table was updated, see [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/). Query Notifications, the technology the powers this mechanism, is usable from both ODBC and from OleDB. See [Working with Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx). With SqlClient managed client you could use LINQ with [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/), but I guess that avenue is closed for MFC native apps.

Comment: sys.dm_qn_subscriptions isn't in sqlserver2000...   if there is a table which is same to it?